# Julia package available from a registry

Tags: julia

I added the package `Knet` with `Pkg.add("Knet")` and noticed that several packages were installed including CUDA. However, after the installation finished when I try:

```
using CUDA
```

it says that this package is not found but that it is available from a registry. It seems that this package is a requirement for `Knet` and it is installed but then one cannot access it right away. Do you know what is happening behind scenes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying mechanism is a bit complex, and is described in detail [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/).

But the general logic is as follows: you can use (with `using` or `import`) the packages that you have explicitly installed. However, such packages might depend on other packages. Julia will automatically decide what other packages are needed to be installed, but they will be not visible in your project unless you explicitly install them.

In fact, typically, on one computer you will have hundreds of packages installed in one place (to avoid having to download and precompile them each time), but each individual project will have access only to packages that you explicitly specify you want to use in this project. The information what packages should be visible in an individual project is typically contained in the Project.toml file as is described [here](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/toml-files/#Project.toml).

You can find more information how to manage projects in Julia [here](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/).